# How to search and replace a string in PHP

Tags: php

I need a PHP function that accepts a string, searches for a certain sub string and then replaces that sub string with something else.

Example:

- Input:  www.google.com/%hello%
- Search for:  %hello%
- Replace with:  hi
- Output:  www.google.com/hi

If anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate it

Oh yeh, the string is within an element of an array example array[this_string],I need to change the contents of the string within the element of the array.

Thanks!

Comment: ++Marc; this kind of question can be easily solved by simply reading the documentation. Please avoid asking this kind of question.

Comment: Pro tip: type the title of your question into Google first: http://www.google.com/search?q=php+search+and+replace+string

Comment: What type of array do you have ? do you need to search and replace inside an array ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = str_replace('%hello%','hi',$str);
```

Answer (score 3):

Read about the str_replace function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
 $raw = 'www.google.com/%hello% Search for: %hello%';
 $str = str_replace("%hello%", "hi", $raw);
 echo $str;
```